# What idiom (any language/culture) this image depicts

Tags: rebus

I was sent this image by somebody today and was told that it is a (close) *story board* of a famous idiom (of some language). The emoticons might not be in order of the idiom's words.
Below is the image.

[image: idiom image]

Comment: What is the second emoticon, is it a hammock ?

Comment: It's a Tanabata Tree I guess

Comment: although it seems to be the tanabata tree (as leoll2 has suggested), but it could represent anything long, green,.. or even the english letter "K". Similarly It could be that the _cool_ emoticon is being re-purposed to represent a blind person since emoji doesn't have a "blind person emoticon".

Comment: or reading this, `The Japanese Tanabata festival celebrates the legend of Hikiboshi and his lover Orihime, the Emperor's daughter, who were permitted to meet only once a year. This Tanabata tree emoji depicts a bamboo stalk hung with a piece of paper on which wishes for the future are written.`, is it actually that tree and the idiom is about two people in love being together for once?

Comment: Any idea which language the idiom is from?

Comment: I strongly suspect this is a Chinese *chengyu*, and that the words are indeed in order.

Comment: @JoeZ. I was thinking the last one is sign language for E.  But I could be wrong.

Comment: But why are the hands curled up into a fist? If it just meant "hand", then it would be open, right?

Comment: Yeah, that was my initial thought too. But the tanzaku is throwing me off.

Comment: Maybe I'm just crazy but I see Okie, for: Okie dokie
http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Okie+Dokie

Comment: @Spacemonkey That's an original idea :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Puzzle answer

The idiom is:

> 胸有成竹

literally translated as

> [to hold an image of bamboo in one's mind](http://mariespastiche.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/chengyu-to-have-image-of-bamboo-in-ones.html)

Explanation:

> [image: image1] - head or mind
>  [image: image2] - bamboo
>  [image: image3] - one
>  [image: image4] - to hold

---

## Language notes and cultural background

This is an instance of

> a Chinese [chengyu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chengyu).
>
>  "Chengyu are mostly derived from ancient literature. The meaning of a chengyu usually surpasses the sum of the meanings carried by the four characters, as chengyu are often intimately linked with the myth, story or historical fact from which they were derived. As such, chengyu do not follow the usual grammatical structure and syntax of the modern Chinese spoken language, and are instead highly compact and synthetic."
>
>  - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chengyu)

The actual meaning of the proverb refers to

> knowing what you intend to accomplish before you begin, and having a well thought out plan or design in your mind which ensures its success.

The story the proverb is based on:

> There once was a scholar, Wen Tong, who was renown for his beautiful bamboo paintings. His pieces were requested almost daily, from near and afar, for it seemed the paintings were so beautiful, you could almost see the leaves fluttering in the wind.
>
>  Wen Tong loved bamboo, and would spend time every day observing it, whether in the forests or within his own gardens which were filled with bamboo. He would observe their stalks and leaves, the way they swayed in the wind or stood upright on calm days, how the colors changed with the light. He spent so much time observing bamboo, that when he sat down to paint it, he had a clear image of bamboo in his mind. That is why his paintings were so beautiful and sought after.
>
>   - [Source](http://mariespastiche.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/chengyu-to-have-image-of-bamboo-in-ones.html)

Comment: I'm afraid I have to disagree on this one if each figure represents one Chinese character in their literal meaning. 胸 - breast / chest, may mean mind metaphorically. 有 - has. 成 - complete or mature. 竹 - bamboo. The position of bamboo is wrong and the "one" is not justified.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @starsplusplus. Your explanation fits the rebus quite well. Actually (since I do not know the actual answer) it is a tie between the "Japanese Tanabata" (see my comment above) and this.
Thanks for the comment ace

Comment: @ace - The puzzle never said that it was one word per character, and it **did** say that the emoticons weren't necessarily in the right order.

Comment: @Ejay The Tanabata is a nice story, but I thought the puzzle was meant to depict an idiom?

Comment: It's just that most Chinese rebus I've seen are one character per image. It might be a non-typical one though.

Comment: @ace Interesting. This is the first time I've seen rebus and chengdu combined, so I wasn't aware that they were normally done like that. It does seem to fit pretty well if you read if as a rebus of the translation given we were told the order didn't matter ("head bamboo one hold" = hold bamboo (in) one's mind). Perhaps the original author wasn't Chinese?

Comment: @starsplusplus You're right about the idiom/story thing. I think I got a bit carried away by how closely the rebus could be related to that story. 
Also the order doesn't matter since all other rebus I was given were not in order of the idiom.

Answer (score 2):

I am almost certain this isn't what you might be looking for, but I can't seem to 'unsee' this option.

> [image: image1] - cool
>  
> [image: image2] - story
>  
> [image: image3] - is best
>  
> [image: image4] - bro (fist)
>  
>  A common English slang idiom for when a friend tells you a story which you don't find interesting, in which you can sarcastically remark "Cool story bro".

Answer (score -2):

The Idiom is: **An empty vessel, makes more noise!!!**

Translation:

1. A man sitting idle makes more noise.
2. A man who does nothing but
   fights more.

Comment: Why do you think that is what the emoji mean? Can you give more details?